# Infinite scroll 'couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL' despite correct path being parsed

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I've got a page which I setup infinite scroll on and it was, the last time I looked, working without issue.

I've gone back to it today and it cannot parse my next selector. I'm getting the following from debug;

> Sorry, we couldn't parse your Next (Previous Posts) URL. Verify your the css selector points to the correct A tag. If you still get this error: yell, scream, and kindly ask for help at infinite-scroll.com.

But it does also log a few extras so some things are working and 'determinePath' is the correct path from the next link;

```
["determinePath", "/en-gb/news-media/videos/videos/"]
pixelsFromNavToBottom: 663
["Binding", "bind"]
```

My JS looks like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var container = $('.masonry'), masonry;

        // Masonry stuff goes on here            

        container.infinitescroll({
            debug: true,
            navSelector  : '#panel-area ul.navigation',    
            nextSelector : '#panel-area ul.navigation li.child.descendant a:first',  
            itemSelector : '#panel-area div.item.video',     
            loading: {
                finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
        },
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
            // ensure that videos load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                // show videos now they're ready
                $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });
        }
        );
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

HTML;

```
<div id="panel-area" class="gallery_grid">
    <div class="masonry js-masonry">
        <div class="item video 2280" data-video-id="2280"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="child descendant">
            <a href="/en-gb/news-media/videos/videos/">14/04/2014</a>
        </li>
        <li class="child descendant">
            <a href="/en-gb/news-media/videos/1342014/">13/4/2014</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `href` of that first link is correctly parsed and assigned to "determinePath". Furthermore, when I apply jQuery to those selectors in the console each returns exactly what I expect.

I've tried to include pathParse, but that then loads from a none existent URL ;

```
pathParse: function () {
    var path = $('#panel-area ul.navigation li a:first').attr('href');
    return [path, '']
}
```

That then performs a get request on `/en-gb/news-media/videos/videos/2/` which doesn't exist :(

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hey man how can you resolve it please help me i got same error. thanks

Comment: @renishkhunt Unfortunately I don't think I ever solved this. I think my issue lead to discovering a limitation of the library. I don't think it was able to do what I needed.

Comment: thanks marksweb for replay.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide "Path" of the url if the url is fixed. It's there in the option list of infinite scroll js

For Example -

```
 path:function generatePageUrl(currentPageNumber) { return ("/path/to/resource/page/" + currentPageNumber + "/html"); }
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about this question. I contacted the dev & it turns out that it requires your next pages to be in an incremented number format but mine weren't. So because my next page wasn't on `/2/` infinite scroll couldn't load it. This was admitted as a limitation with an improvement in the next version to allow an arbitrary value.